# Use different index.html if mobile in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app, where we have a index.html(the one in the public folder thats used as the initial template) with a lot of stuff and then we render a small React part on a div with an id of root.

But, we need to show a different index.html if the client is mobile, say lower than 500px for example.

I dont want to do this when react is ready...

I want to do this, before we load react to the div with id of root.

So that it its mobile, it loads a different index.html, the one that exists on the public folder.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have access to browser's width with javascript. if you don't want to handle that with javascript, the only way is to handle that from server side. You must decide which template you want to send to front-end with `User Agent` header.
But I don't recommend that to you unless you have a good reason for this.